# How to parse .ts file with playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, playwright

I have electron application made with vue.js and I would like to add playwright testing.

I am testing this with node 16.10.0, npm 7.24.0, electron 23,"vite": "^3.0.9", "@playwright/test": "^1.35.0".

I have "type": "module" in package.json.

I have this test.spec.ts -

```
import { test, _electron } from '@playwright/test'

test('App Launches and quits', async() => {
    const app = await _electron.launch({args: ['./index.html']});
    const window = await app.firstWindow();
    await window.waitForSelector('pin-wrap');
});
```

Then I have this index.html which is calling main.ts -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <title>abc</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.ts -

```
import('./main.electron.ts');
...
```

But at this place everything ends, cause it understands the .ts as text/plain. When I use .js instead of .ts it works but then again there are vue import problems. I get this error -

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Someone called this devops config hell. Wondering what is the easiest thing I can do here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried putting the vite dev server as the URL instead of the index.html?